Commutator Ideal of Toeplitz Operators
Suppose $H^{2}$ is a Hardy space and $T_{\phi}$ is Toeplitz operator on $H^{2}$ with symbol $\phi\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$. $\mathcal{A}$ is a C*-algebra generated by $\{T_{\phi}:\phi\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})\}$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ is the smallest closed ideal of $\mathcal{A}$ containing all the commutators of $\mathcal{A}$ i.e. $\mathcal{C}$ is the commutator ideal of $\mathcal{A}$. Then how to get the form of an element of $\mathcal{C}$?
That is arising from Banach Algebra Technique in Operator Theory by R.G. Douglas (Theorem : 7.11)

Do you mean the formula for a dense subset appearing in the proof of theorem 7.11?

Yes. How the expression of K given in the proof is coming that I am not getting,

One can show that a commutator ideal $\mathcal{C}$ of a $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is the closure of the set of elements of the form
$$
\sum_i A_i [C_i,D_i] B_i ,
$$
where $A_i, B_i, C_i, D_i\in \mathcal{A}$. Indeed, let $\mathcal{J}'$ denote such closure. It is a closed two-sided ideal (check this), therefore it is self-adjoint. Obviously, $\mathcal{J}' \subset \mathcal{J}$. But since any commutator is in $\mathcal{J}'$ and $\mathcal{J}$ is the smallest ideal containing commutators, we get $\mathcal{J} =\mathcal{J}'$.
Let $\mathcal{A}_0$ be a set of generators of $\mathcal{A}$, and $\mathcal{J}''$ be the closure of the set of elements of the form
$$
\sum_i \prod_k A_{ik} [C_i,D_i] \prod_j B_{ij} ,
$$
where $A_{ik}, B_{ij}, C_i, D_i\in \mathcal{A}_0$. Check that $\mathcal{J} = \mathcal{J}''$ (hint: using that any element of $\mathcal{A}$ can be approximated by linear combinations of elements of the form $\prod_i A_i$, $A_i \in \mathcal{A}_0$, show that any commutator is in $\mathcal{J}''$).
Now, according to Theorem 6.32 in the book you mentioned, you have that the set of elements $\psi \overline{\phi}$ with $\psi \in H^\infty$, $\phi$ an inner function, forms a dense subalgebra of $L_\infty(\mathbb{T})$. Elements $T_a$, $a \in L_\infty$ generate $\mathcal{A}$. Therefore $\mathcal{A}_0 =\{ T_{\psi \overline{\phi}} \colon \psi \in H^\infty, \phi \text{ an inner function}\}$ generates $\mathcal{A}$ as well.
Thus, by taking $B_{ij}, C_i, D_i$ from $\mathcal{A}_0$ we can approximate any element of the ideal $\mathcal{C}$ by elements of the form $K$ in the referenced proof of Theorem 7.11.

How does the form of an element in generated ideal follow the above expression. In the expression of K how the product terms are coming is not clear. Can you duly explain?

@Halmos Can you please specify your question? Do you understand why the ideal generated by $S$ looks like this? Do you understand that the set of elements $T_{\psi\overline{\phi}}$ is a dense algebra?

I haven't understood clearly.

I've reformulated the answer to make it clearer.

Thank you @pllnt

How  $K(\theta f)$ =0  is coming $f\in H^{2}$ ?
